# SBT shell project in terminal gives error

Tags: sbt-native-packager

i am a beginner at scala programming language. i read sbt documentation and implement these in sbt shell but it gives error. how to resolve it?

....................

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.0"
ThisBuild / organization := "com.example"

val scalaTest = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.7"
val gigahorse = "com.eed3si9n" %% "gigahorse-okhttp" % "0.5.0"
val playJson  = "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.9"

lazy val hello = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(helloCore)
  .dependsOn(helloCore)
  .settings(
    name := "Hello",
    libraryDependencies += scalaTest % Test,
  )

lazy val helloCore = (project in file("core"))
  .settings(
    name := "Hello Core",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(gigahorse, playJson),
    libraryDependencies += scalaTest % Test,
  )
```

...............................the above is my build.sbt file...............

```
       package example.core

import gigahorse._, support.okhttp.Gigahorse
import scala.concurrent._, duration._
import play.api.libs.json._

object Weather {
  lazy val http = Gigahorse.http(Gigahorse.config)

  def weather: Future[String] = {
    val baseUrl = "https://www.metaweather.com/api/location"
    val locUrl = baseUrl + "/search/"
    val weatherUrl = baseUrl + "/%s/"
    val rLoc = Gigahorse.url(locUrl).get.
      addQueryString("query" -> "New York")
    import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    for {
      loc <- http.run(rLoc, parse)
      woeid = (loc \ 0  \ "woeid").get
      rWeather = Gigahorse.url(weatherUrl format woeid).get
      weather <- http.run(rWeather, parse)
    } yield (weather \\ "weather_state_name")(0).as[String].toLowerCase
  }

  private def parse = Gigahorse.asString andThen Json.parse
}
```

...........................................hello.scala....................

```
package example

import scala.concurrent._, duration._
import core.Weather

object Hello extends App {
  val w = Await.result(Weather.weather, 10.seconds)
  println(s"Hello! The weather in New York is $w.")
  Weather.http.close()
}
```

**error:**

```
mehveen@mehveen-Y11C:~$ cd foo-build
mehveen@mehveen-Y11C:~/foo-build$ touch build.sbt
mehveen@mehveen-Y11C:~/foo-build$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/mehveen/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading settings for project foo-build-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /home/mehveen/foo-build/project
[info] Loading settings for project hello from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to Hello (in build file:/home/mehveen/foo-build/)
[info] sbt server started at local:///home/mehveen/.sbt/1.0/server/704a39d101f4d89588ee/sock
sbt:Hello> run
[info] Updating helloCore...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.13;2.6.9
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/mehveen/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.13/2.6.9/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-json_2.13/2.6.9/play-json_2.13-2.6.9.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /home/mehveen/.sbt/preloaded/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.13/2.6.9/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////home/mehveen/.sbt/preloaded/com/typesafe/play/play-json_2.13/2.6.9/play-json_2.13-2.6.9.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.13;2.6.9: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.typesafe.play:play-json_2.13:2.6.9 (/home/mehveen/foo-build/build.sbt#L19)
[warn]        +- com.example:hello-core_2.13:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.13;2.6.9: not found
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:332)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:208)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:239)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:204)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:199)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:196)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:238)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:193)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:45)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:93)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(LibraryManagement.scala:106)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:106)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:89)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:120)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2561)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[error] (helloCore / update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.13;2.6.9: not found
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed 16 Apr. 2021, 5:00:08 pm
```

[error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSww0.png)

Comment: What error? Regarding what code? [Edit] to explain your exact problem and quote any errors in full.